# React-slick hide pagination dots on last slide

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I am using [React-Slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/) component in my project. I have to show pagination dots on all the slides except the last slide. I want to hide those pagination dots for last slide.

I have checked that `afterChange` function is available as a callback. This can be used to customise the slider css in jQuery, but how can I use this function to hide the pagination dots in React application?

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';

export default class Carousal extends Component {
render() {
    let settings = {
        accessibility: true,
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '10px',
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                swipeToSlide: true
            }
        }],
        afterChange: function (currentSlide) {
           console.log(currentSlide);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Slider {...settings} >
            {slides}
        </Slider>
    );
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Can you give a little example please?

Comment: Updated code. Please check above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Components construction set state value for dots prop for the Slider component. Then set it to false when you don't want to show it.

```
export default class Carousal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dots: true
    };
  }
  render() {
    let settings = {
      accessibility: true,
      dots: this.state.dots,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '10px',
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          swipeToSlide: true
        }
      }],
      afterChange: (currentSlide) => {
        console.log(currentSlide);
        this.setState({
          dots: (currentSlide !== 'yourDesiredSlide')
        });
      }
    };

    return (
      <Slider {...settings} >
        {slides}
      </Slider>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm :)

But you will have to bind `this` in `afterChange` function to get it working. Otherwise there is error: `React Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function`

Comment: Yes you are right. My mistake. You can also use arrow function to not have to bind `this`. Updated my answer.